# Formulatext scenarios

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

In one sheet I have this formula

[image]

I want to extract the part after the `+` from the formula and use it in a second formula on another sheet. I did this via:

```
RIGHT(FORMULATEXT('Sum by Type'!E24),(LEN(FORMULATEXT('Sum by Type'!E24))-FIND("+",FORMULATEXT('Sum by Type'!E24))))*1000
```

My problem is, sometimes it's not a `+` but a `-`. I know I can do an `if` to determine the operator for `find` but this is already a part of a `choose` formula that is way too long XD Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking for SUMs¹ closing bracket. The [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD) should remove problems with the length.

```
MID(FORMULATEXT('Sum by Type'!E24), FIND(")", FORMULATEXT('Sum by Type'!E24))+2, 99)*1000
```

---

¹ <sub>[SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57)</sub>